# How can I create kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

I read 'Creating Apps in Kivy'. And there is the code like below.

```
from kivy.app import App

App().run()


class WeatherApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WeatherApp().run()
```

After finishing above code, the Book said you create kv file in the same directory as main.py.
But I don't how to create kv file.
How??
help me~~

Comment: 1) create a file 2) change the extension to `.kv`

Comment: create .py file and change extension??

Comment: I find how to load kv file.
http://sakeofgrowth.blogspot.kr/2015/02/creating-gui-program-in-python-with.html

Comment: A file is a file. Just create a text file and change the extension. It's an extremely simple operation really

Comment: Thank~I solved it~

Answer (score 5):

In my case the file was saving as "filename.kv.txt" or "filename.kv.py".
I could not change it until I enabled **"File name extensions"** in File Explorer

[image: Enable File name extensions]

Answer (score 4):

Ok i see you are referring to tutorials [here](https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html).

- You can create file by right click in that directory.give it .kv extension.
- Or in the terminal use gedit weather.kv

Now u can carry on tutorial.There are nice set of tutorial on youtube by
inclement(Alexander Taylor).[link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdNh1e1kmiPP4YApJm8ENK2yMlwF1_edq)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the type of file: from "python files" to "All files" and save it with the .kv extension.